# Экспорт .csv файла в mysql (Кодировка)

Tags: mysql, кодировка, csv

возник вопрос при экспорте .csv файла в mysql.

Есть csv-файл c полученный из excel таблицы (кодировка задана utf8 при помощи Notepad++).

Пытаюсь экспортировать его при помощи запроса:

```
set names utf8;
USE `API`;
CREATE TABLE temptable (
`Param` LONGTEXT, 
`Name` LONGTEXT,
`Fn` LONGTEXT,
`Dy` LONGTEXT,
`TypeId` LONGTEXT,
`TypeFn` LONGTEXT
) CHARACTER SET=utf8;


LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\Uploads\\file.csv'
INTO TABLE temptable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Запрос выполняется без ошибок, однако полученная таблица в mysql выглядит следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что-то не так с кодировкой (кириллица неадекватно отображается). Что нужно сделать, чтобы исправить?

В файл my.ini добавлены настройки кодировки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарна за ответ.

Comment: Это с точки зрения MySQL - импорт.

Comment: *однако полученная таблица выглядит следующим образом:* ГДЕ она так выглядит? вот именно это ГДЕ и настраивайте.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо большое за ответ, однако, в MySQL кодировку тоже задала utf8 (см. код). Возможно нужно сделать еще какие-то настройки?

Comment: Какая программа используется для просмотра? нафиг её, CLI в зубы - и смотрите.

Comment: @Akina, mysql workbench

Comment: А чем CLI поможет?

Comment: Ну если Вы не можете выставить отображение UTF-8 вместо ANSI (?) в воркбенче - может, Вы сможете запустить utf8mb4-консольный клиент с готового ярлыка (или, если он куда-то подевался, вручную добавите `"--default-character-set=utf8"` в командную строку запуска клиента) и убедитесь, что данные в таблицах лежат с правильной кодировкой?

Comment: default-character-set=utf8 добавлен в конфигурационный файл my.ini, в CLI вывела значения чарсетов (добавила рисунок см. выше), попыталась там же вывести таблицу, все равно непонятные символы вместо русских букв

Comment: Ну теперь там же в консоли сделайте `SELECT * FROM temptable LIMIT 10` и смотрите, что выведется. Если криво - показывайте вывод `SHOW CREATE TABLE temptable`.

Comment: Нашла решение проблемы, спасибо большое. Изначально созданная мною база данных была в latin1. Проблема решена аналогично https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/9084386

Comment: *Изначально созданная мною база данных была в latin1.* Мда... а в тексте вопроса - иначе... жаль, что Вы не проверили это сразу.